# java switch performance optimize

Tags: java, performance, switch-statement

I'm running into a strange performance issue related to switch when tried to parse a json string. please refer to the sample code below:

```
public class SwitchTest {
private static final String jsonString = "{\"person\":[{\"id\":-2147483648,\"firstName\":\"4809981875dc43ddb6d1add0b1eec75c><\\\"<//> ' \\\"\",\"lastName\":\"4809981875dc43ddb6d1add0b1eec75c\",\"address1\":\"4809981875dc43ddb6d1add0b1eec75c\",\"postCode\":\"4809981875dc43ddb6d1add0b1eec75c\",\"city\":\"4809981875dc43ddb6d1add0b1eec75c\",\"country\":\"4809981875dc43ddb6d1add0b1eec75c\",\"birthday\":\"2014-03-04T00:12:06Z\",\"active\":true},{\"id\":-2147483648,\"firstName\":\"3b21ba46239b484ea1d1b7d9dbee68c0><\\\"<//> ' \\\"\",\"lastName\":\"3b21ba46239b484ea1d1b7d9dbee68c0\",\"address1\":\"3b21ba46239b484ea1d1b7d9dbee68c0\",\"postCode\":\"3b21ba46239b484ea1d1b7d9dbee68c0\",\"city\":\"3b21ba46239b484ea1d1b7d9dbee68c0\",\"country\":\"3b21ba46239b484ea1d1b7d9dbee68c0\",\"birthday\":\"2014-03-04T00:12:06Z\",\"active\":true},{\"id\":-2147483648,\"firstName\":\"c953f8ebaaae4424a656c819b8149376><\\\"<//> ' \\\"\",\"lastName\":\"c953f8ebaaae4424a656c819b8149376\",\"address1\":\"c953f8ebaaae4424a656c819b8149376\",\"postCode\":\"c953f8ebaaae4424a656c819b8149376\",\"city\":\"c953f8ebaaae4424a656c819b8149376\",\"country\":\"c953f8ebaaae4424a656c819b8149376\",\"birthday\":\"2014-03-04T00:12:06Z\",\"active\":true},{\"id\":-2147483648,\"firstName\":\"d75587f037324efaafc88de095416221><\\\"<//> ' \\\"\",\"lastName\":\"d75587f037324efaafc88de095416221\",\"address1\":\"d75587f037324efaafc88de095416221\",\"postCode\":\"d75587f037324efaafc88de095416221\",\"city\":\"d75587f037324efaafc88de095416221\",\"country\":\"d75587f037324efaafc88de095416221\",\"birthday\":\"2014-03-04T00:12:06Z\",\"active\":true},{\"id\":-2147483648,\"firstName\":\"e8291a6104094e94b81daf4cf1852efe><\\\"<//> ' \\\"\",\"lastName\":\"e8291a6104094e94b81daf4cf1852efe\",\"address1\":\"e8291a6104094e94b81daf4cf1852efe\",\"postCode\":\"e8291a6104094e94b81daf4cf1852efe\",\"city\":\"e8291a6104094e94b81daf4cf1852efe\",\"country\":\"e8291a6104094e94b81daf4cf1852efe\",\"birthday\":\"2014-03-04T00:12:06Z\",\"active\":true},{\"id\":-2147483648,\"firstName\":\"63f0816b82eb42a8be9181e4a733285a><\\\"<//> ' \\\"\",\"lastName\":\"63f0816b82eb42a8be9181e4a733285a\",\"address1\":\"63f0816b82eb42a8be9181e4a733285a\",\"postCode\":\"63f0816b82eb42a8be9181e4a733285a\",\"city\":\"63f0816b82eb42a8be9181e4a733285a\",\"country\":\"63f0816b82eb42a8be9181e4a733285a\",\"birthday\":\"2014-03-04T00:12:06Z\",\"active\":true},{\"id\":-2147483648,\"firstName\":\"26019c0c46ef487dae175c1bae381417><\\\"<//> ' \\\"\",\"lastName\":\"26019c0c46ef487dae175c1bae381417\",\"address1\":\"26019c0c46ef487dae175c1bae381417\",\"postCode\":\"26019c0c46ef487dae175c1bae381417\",\"city\":\"26019c0c46ef487dae175c1bae381417\",\"country\":\"26019c0c46ef487dae175c1bae381417\",\"birthday\":\"2014-03-04T00:12:06Z\",\"active\":true},{\"id\":-2147483648,\"firstName\":\"a917a9d6628d4afea75ff6212df3bd32><\\\"<//> ' \\\"\",\"lastName\":\"a917a9d6628d4afea75ff6212df3bd32\",\"address1\":\"a917a9d6628d4afea75ff6212df3bd32\",\"postCode\":\"a917a9d6628d4afea75ff6212df3bd32\",\"city\":\"a917a9d6628d4afea75ff6212df3bd32\",\"country\":\"a917a9d6628d4afea75ff6212df3bd32\",\"birthday\":\"2014-03-04T00:12:06Z\",\"active\":true},{\"id\":-2147483648,\"firstName\":\"ef7663f41de648bf8d4a53e32ab0c386><\\\"<//> ' \\\"\",\"lastName\":\"ef7663f41de648bf8d4a53e32ab0c386\",\"address1\":\"ef7663f41de648bf8d4a53e32ab0c386\",\"postCode\":\"ef7663f41de648bf8d4a53e32ab0c386\",\"city\":\"ef7663f41de648bf8d4a53e32ab0c386\",\"country\":\"ef7663f41de648bf8d4a53e32ab0c386\",\"birthday\":\"2014-03-04T00:12:06Z\",\"active\":true},{\"id\":-2147483648,\"firstName\":\"c56ae519a31a4f478da29b9eac61a426><\\\"<//> ' \\\"\",\"lastName\":\"c56ae519a31a4f478da29b9eac61a426\",\"address1\":\"c56ae519a31a4f478da29b9eac61a426\",\"postCode\":\"c56ae519a31a4f478da29b9eac61a426\",\"city\":\"c56ae519a31a4f478da29b9eac61a426\",\"country\":\"c56ae519a31a4f478da29b9eac61a426\",\"birthday\":\"2014-03-04T00:12:06Z\",\"active\":true}]}";
private static int[] caseArray = new int[128];

static {
    caseArray[','] = 1;
    caseArray[':'] = 1;
    caseArray['"'] = 1;
    caseArray['{'] = 1;
    caseArray['}'] = 1;
    caseArray['['] = 1;
    caseArray[']'] = 1;
}

@Test
public void testSwitchPerformance() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int loopNum = 100000;

    for (int i = 0; i < loopNum; i++) {
        switch_1();
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("switch_1 took: " + (endTime - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < loopNum; i++) {
        switch_2();
    }

    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("switch_2 took: " + (endTime - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < loopNum; i++) {
        switch_3();
    }

    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("switch_3 took: " + (endTime - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < loopNum; i++) {
        switch_4();
    }

    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("switch_4 took: " + (endTime - startTime));
}

@Test
public void switch_1() {
    char ch = 0;

    for (int i = 0, len = jsonString.length(); i < len; i++) {
        ch = jsonString.charAt(i);

        switch (ch) {
        case ',':
            break;

        case ':':
            break;

        case '"':
            break;

        case '{':
            break;

        case '}':
            break;

        case '[':
            break;

        case ']':
            break;

        default:
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void switch_2() {
    int ch = 0;

    for (int i = 0, len = jsonString.length(); i < len; i++) {
        ch = jsonString.charAt(i);

        switch (ch) {
        case 1: // no char equals 1 in the json string.
            break;

        case ',':
            break;

        case ':':
            break;

        case '"':
            break;

        case '{':
            break;

        case '}':
            break;

        case '[':
            break;

        case ']':
            break;

        default:
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void switch_3() {
    int ch = 0;

    for (int i = 0, len = jsonString.length(); i < len; i++) {
        ch = jsonString.charAt(i);

        if (ch == ',') {
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == ':') {
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == '"') {
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == '{') {
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == '}') {
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == ']') {
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == '[') {
            continue;
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void switch_4() {
    int ch = 0;

    for (int i = 0, len = jsonString.length(); i < len; i++) {
        ch = jsonString.charAt(i);

        if (caseArray[ch] > 0) {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the result running on: Windows 7/JDK1.7_51

switch_1 took: 474, switch_2 took: 5, switch_3 took: 6, switch_4 took: 129

The only difference between switch_1 and switch_2 is one more "case 1:"
why the switch_1 is so slow?

Comment: by the way, I checked the class file, both switch_1 and switch_2 are compiled with lookupswitch:
     21  lookupswitch default: 117
          case 1: 96
          case 34: 105
          case 44: 99
          case 58: 102
          case 91: 114
          case 93: 117
          case 123: 108
          case 125: 111


     21  lookupswitch default: 106
          case 34: 94
          case 44: 88
          case 58: 91
          case 91: 103
          case 93: 106
          case 123: 97
          case 125: 100

Comment: change the order of the execution, to see if it changes the result.

Comment: it's same. switch_2 is still tens, (even hundred times with big string) faster than switch_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

switch_1, your first benchmark, measures the performance of code that is not JIT optimized, plus, the JIT compilation itself.

Please run testSwitchPerformance at least three times.

If you do more benchmarks like this, I recommend using [JUnit benchmarks](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html). It does warmup and benchmarks runs and calculates the average and standard deviation of the result, so you know whether you are on the right way.

Comment: thank you. i did run the test by another Util class: with the code below:
<code>

    @Test
    public void testSwitchPerformance_2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Profiler.run(this, "switch_1", 1, 100000).printResult();
            Profiler.run(this, "switch_2", 1, 100000).printResult();
            Profiler.run(this, "switch_3", 1, 100000).printResult();
            Profiler.run(this, "switch_4", 1, 100000).printResult();
        }
    }
</code>

Comment: The result is same: the fastest result by swith_1 is: 0.0042, it's 0.0001 by switch_2, which much more faster than switch_1. how do i know is JIT optimized or not? the reason why i concern the performance is because switch_1 could be hundred times slower than switch_2 if i try to parse a big string(3M) and met the a serious issue. (class 'Profiler' has dependence to another *.jar file, what's why i didn't put code above).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. After the fourth round it seems quite stable, I got: switch_1 took: 469, switch_2 took: 429, switch_3 took: 0, switch_4 took: 121

Comment: BTW: The only reason I can think of why switch_3 is so fast, is,because the dead code is completely eleminated by the compiler...

Comment: Though, from the timings and the comparison to what I measure on my machine, your switch_2 is only so fast, because the switch was eleminated by the compiler. I suggest that you profile the whole parser actually doing something. Microbenchmarks may be a big pitfall.